# how to work with const in a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I'm having problems with this call:

```
m_baseMap.find(baseName)->second->AddVehicale(vehicaleToAdd);
```

There's a red line under `m_baseMap`, the error is : "the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function". The base map is defined as the following:

```
map <string, const Base*> m_baseMap;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the `AddVehicale` member function const-qualified?  If not, then you can't call it via a `const Base*`.  The question asked in the title seems unrelated to the problem you describe in the text.

Comment: @James +1 for not getting distracted by the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with the `find()` but with the call AddVehicale because the map specifies `const Base*`. You either need to make the `map` be `map<string, Base *>` or make sure `AddVehicale` is a const method (which means you are promising not to modify the object pointed to in the map)  e.g. `void Base::AddVehicale(Vehicale &v) const;`

As far as I know, the compiler will choose whether to use the const find or the non-const find based on whether the map itself is const at the time (like if you have a const reference to the map)

P.S. Vehicale is spelled Vehicle (I use google to spell check if I'm not sure, search for the word and it will suggest the correct spelling)

Comment: i can't make the AddVehicle const, what do you mean "make the map be map"?

Comment: It should have been map<string, Base *> (without the const)

Comment: Liberal use of backticks can help with disappearing template argument lists :-).

Comment: @Roy your member function `AddVehicale()` does not guarantee that it doesn't change its object. To make this guarantee you need to sign it as `AddVicale(...) const;`  Alternatively, change the map to `map<string, Base*>`.